# JSF-2 Custom tag to change the styleClass for the child's element

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tags

I use JSF 2. I need to write a custom tag which changes the style class for messages inside of it.
So if I have such code:

```
<my:errorGrid errorClass="#{richBean.erClass}" >
   <my:inputField id="pid1" value="#{richBean.pid}" fsType="pid">
   </my:inputField>

  <h:message for="pid1" ajaxRendered="true"/>

</my:errorGrid>
```

Error message should be outputted with additional styleClass. The name of this styleClass is taken from the attribute *errorClass* of the custom tag **my:errorGrid**

As I undrstand I need to use **vcp:body** tag in template and process children in *encodeChildren()* method. Please, could anybody provide me some hints how to realize it? Maybe some advice or links.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a composite component?

**errorGrid.xhtml**

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="errorClass"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <my:inputField id="pid1" value="#{richBean.pid}" fsType="pid">
    </my:inputField>

    <h:message for="pid1" ajaxRendered="true" errorClass="#{cc.attrs.errorClass}"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

If you have a classical component though, you simply have to call `HtmlMessage.setErrorClass()` with your error class before rendering. e.g:

```
for (UIComponent child : getChildren()){
    if(child instanceof HtmlMessage) {
        HtmlMessage msgComp = (HtmlMessage) child;
        msgComp.setErrorClass(getErrorClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it should be a tag with an attribute. Now I am trying to solve the problem with encodeChildren() and vcp:body. But still I have some dififficalties and no info/documentation...

Comment: It is a component with an attribute. You can use it like `<errorGrid errorClass="foo">.